# Parse Cloud Code getting Error Failed with: TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'set'

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im using Cloud Code for my Android App.
After saving a Value to a Parse Class I want to Update a field (credits) from my Users.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("householdOf", request.params.household);  
query.find({
success: function(roomMates) {
for (var roomMate in roomMates)
{
 if(roomMate != currentUser)
 {
   roomMate.set(
    {
      credit: 3   
    }, 
    {
        error: function(gameTurnAgain, error) 
        {
            console.log("set failed " +error.code + error.message);
            response.error("error");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

this is my Cloud Code. I get the Error (TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'set') by roomMate.set
The roomMates must be Parse.User or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not professional in JS, but I am also playing with parse Cloude Code. So I suppose that you enumerate roomMates incorrectly.

You should enumerate array and get object like:

```
for (var i=0; i<roomMates.length; i++) {
 roomMate = roomMates[i];
}
```

The `key in` enumerator works in key-value dictionaries to enumerate keys.

```
var dictionary = {key1 : "Hi", key2: "Bye"};
for (var key in dictionary) {
 obj = dictionary[key];
}
```